# PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have problem with this code :

input : import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

input : x_train.columns
output : Index(['Year', 'Life_expectancy ', 'Adult_Mortality', 'infant_deaths',
'Alcohol', 'percentage_expenditure', 'Hepatitis_B', 'Measles ', ' BMI ',
'under_five_deaths ', 'Polio', 'Total_expenditure', 'Diphtheria ',
' HIV_or_AIDS', 'GDP', 'Population', ' thinness_1_19_years',
' thinness_5_9_years', 'Income_composition_of_resources', 'Schooling'],
dtype='object')

input : model = smf.ols(formula='Life_expectancy ~ BMI', data=x_train).fit()
print(model.summary())
output : PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'Life_expectancy' is not defined
Life_expectancy

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMaFf.png)

it showing error and i don't know what happen

kindly need your help

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't work because there is a space at the end of the Life_expectancy column name and BMI column name too.
If you remove these spaces it should work.